# Create Widget in Unreal Engine 4 blueprints not working?

Tags: unreal-engine4, unreal-blueprint

I am trying to build an interface of my RTS, I want to create basic HUD with some buttons and time/date grid.

I have created widget blueprint and designed as I needed.

This is how I am trying to create HUD, get its reference and put it into variable for next use.

[image]

This is how I am trying to add it to the viewport on the beginPlay.

[image]

Everything is happening inside PlayerController. No widget is shown on the display.

Answer (score 1):

I tested and it works well using your way, UE4 version is 4.21.
Let me know if that doesn't work for you.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Well, it is not working for me. !https://imgur.com/7jFO854 !https://imgur.com/wzrlpZx !https://imgur.com/ZMTWL9C !https://imgur.com/y1cCmyI

Comment: I use UE 4.20.3

Comment: Could you add a big button on the top screen for testing, or use 4.21 try again?

Comment: Tried this in 4.21.2 but still not working, also added big button into middle of screen, nothing is shown. I am desparate, it should be so easy.

Comment: Issue Fixed, I used character as default player pawn and everything works now.